# chartjs horizontal bar chart spacing broken between 2.7.1 and 2.7.1

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart

I created a horizontal bar chart with Chartjs using JSFiddle.  I was able to tweak it and get it looking pretty close to my final version, as you can see here:  https://jsfiddle.net/coder_jb/pLec5hqn/

However, when I tried and it inside my web development IDE I was having issues with the bar vertical spacing.  I spent more time than I care to admit tracking down the difference and it came down to Chartjs versions.  The one that works as expected uses version 2.7.1, but  the same code in JSFiddle using the 2.7.2 version (https://jsfiddle.net/coder_jb/3tnrzeLq/4/) compresses the vertical bar spacing.  So either I'm coding something wrong and got lucky in the earlier version, or something is possibly broken in the 2.7.2 version.  Any idea why this is happening?

**GOOD (Using Chartjs 2.7.1):**

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
let barChart = null;

let barData = [
  25, 20, 13, 24, 15, 26, 17, 28, 19, 30,
  11, 32, 13, 34, 15, 35, 16, 37, 18, 39
];

let barTooltips = [
  "host_1 (127.0.0.1) eth33", "host_1 (127.0.0.1) eth34",
  "host_2 (127.0.0.2) eth33", "host_2 (127.0.0.2) eth34",
  "host_3 (127.0.0.3) eth34", "host_3 (127.0.0.3) eth35",
  "host_4 (127.0.0.4) eth7", "host_4 (127.0.0.4) eth8",
  "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth9", "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth10",
  "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth11", "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth12",
  "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth13", "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth14",
  "host_6 (127.0.0.6) eth15", "host_7 (127.0.0.7) eth16",
  "host_8 (127.0.0.8) eth17", "host_8 (127.0.0.8) eth18",
  "host_9 (127.0.0.9) eth19", "host_9 (127.0.0.9) eth20"
];
let rcBackgroundColors = [
  '#00b0ff', '#43a047',
  '#ff8f00', '#c62828',
  '#df00f9', '#ffea00',
  '#4e342e', '#2979ff',
  '#00e676', '#ffc400',
  '#5cbae6', '#b6d957',
  '#fac364', '#8cd3ff',
  '#d998cb', '#f2d249',
  '#93b9c6', '#cc5a8',
  '#52bacc', '#dbdb46'
];
let ticYlabels = [];
let ticYlabelsHidden = [];

function updateTicYlabelsHidden(ticLabel) {
  if (ticLabel) {
    if (ticYlabelsHidden.includes(ticLabel)) {
      ticYlabelsHidden.splice(ticYlabelsHidden.indexOf(ticLabel), 1);
      //ticYlabels.push(ticLabel);
    } else {
      ticYlabelsHidden.push(ticLabel);
    }
  }
  initializeTicYlabels();
}

function initializeTicYlabels() {
  ticYlabels = [];
  for (let n = 0; n < barTooltips.length; ++n) {
    let label = barTooltips[n].split(" ");
    label.shift();
    let ticLabel = label.join(' ');
    if (!ticYlabelsHidden.includes(ticLabel))
      ticYlabels.push(ticLabel);
  }
}

initializeTicYlabels();

let barBackgroundColor = [];
let maxColors = 20;
let barDataSets = [];
for (let n = 0; n < barTooltips.length; ++n) {
  barBackgroundColor.push(rcBackgroundColors[n % maxColors]);
  barDataSets[n] = {
    label: [ticYlabels[n]],
    data: [barData[n]],
    backgroundColor: rcBackgroundColors[n % maxColors],
    borderColor: rcBackgroundColors[n % maxColors],
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBorderWidth: 0
  };
}

let xMax = Math.max(...barData);
xMax += xMax / 10;
let pktSrcBarChartConfig = {
  animation: false,
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    datasets: barDataSets,
    labels: ticYlabels,
  },

  options: {
    barValueSpacing: 10,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'y',
      callbacks: {
        title: function() {
          return '';
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem) {
          return barTooltips[tooltipItem.index] + ':  ' + tooltipItem.xLabel + ' KB/sec';
        }
      }
    },
    legend: false,
    legendCallback: function(chart) {
      let text = [];
      text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');
      for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
        text.push('<li><i class="fa fa-1x fa-check-square" style="color: ' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + ';">');
        if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
          text.push('&nbsp;<span style="color: black; font-size: 16px; font-family: ubuntu monospace">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label);
        }
        text.push('</i></li>');
      }
      text.push('</ul>');
      return text.join('');
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Bandwidth',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
      fontSize: 18,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'KB/sec',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
          fontSize: 18,
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          suggestedMax: xMax,
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        //id: 'ip',
        //type: 'category',
        barPercentage: 0.8,
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        maxBarThickness: 30,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Packet Source',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
          fontSize: 18,
        },
      }]
    },
    
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return value;
        },
        display: function(context) {
          return context.chart.isDatasetVisible(context.datasetIndex);
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}

function legendClickCallback(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  let target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  while (target.nodeName !== 'LI') {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  let parent = target.parentElement;
  let chartId = parseInt(parent.classList[0].split("-")[0], 10);
  let chart = Chart.instances[chartId];
  let index = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children).indexOf(target);

  if (chart.isDatasetVisible(index)) {
    target.classList.add('hiddenItem');
    target.firstChild.classList.remove('fa-check-square');
    target.firstChild.classList.add('fa-square');
    chart.data.datasets[index].hidden = true;
  } else {
    target.classList.remove('hiddenItem');
    target.firstChild.classList.remove('fa-square');
    target.firstChild.classList.add('fa-check-square');
    chart.data.datasets[index].hidden = false;
  }
  updateTicYlabelsHidden(target.innerText.trim());
  barChart.data.labels = ticYlabels;
  barChart.update();
}

barChart = new Chart(ctx, pktSrcBarChartConfig);
// Generate custom html legend with checkboxes instead of colored rectangles
let myLegendContainer = document.getElementById("legendDiv");
myLegendContainer.innerHTML = barChart.generateLegend();

// Bind onClick event to all LI-tags of the legend
let legendItems = myLegendContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (let i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i += 1) {
  legendItems[i].addEventListener("click", legendClickCallback, false);
}
```

```css
[class="0-legend"] {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: table-row;
}

[class="0-legend"] li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

[class="0-legend"] li.hiddenItem span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="legendDiv" class="noselect"></div>
<div id="container" style="width:95%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**BAD (Using Chartjs 2.7.2):**

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
let barChart = null;

let barData = [
  25, 20, 13, 24, 15, 26, 17, 28, 19, 30,
  11, 32, 13, 34, 15, 35, 16, 37, 18, 39
];

let barTooltips = [
  "host_1 (127.0.0.1) eth33", "host_1 (127.0.0.1) eth34",
  "host_2 (127.0.0.2) eth33", "host_2 (127.0.0.2) eth34",
  "host_3 (127.0.0.3) eth34", "host_3 (127.0.0.3) eth35",
  "host_4 (127.0.0.4) eth7", "host_4 (127.0.0.4) eth8",
  "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth9", "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth10",
  "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth11", "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth12",
  "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth13", "host_5 (127.0.0.5) eth14",
  "host_6 (127.0.0.6) eth15", "host_7 (127.0.0.7) eth16",
  "host_8 (127.0.0.8) eth17", "host_8 (127.0.0.8) eth18",
  "host_9 (127.0.0.9) eth19", "host_9 (127.0.0.9) eth20"
];
let rcBackgroundColors = [
  '#00b0ff', '#43a047',
  '#ff8f00', '#c62828',
  '#df00f9', '#ffea00',
  '#4e342e', '#2979ff',
  '#00e676', '#ffc400',
  '#5cbae6', '#b6d957',
  '#fac364', '#8cd3ff',
  '#d998cb', '#f2d249',
  '#93b9c6', '#cc5a8',
  '#52bacc', '#dbdb46'
];
let ticYlabels = [];
let ticYlabelsHidden = [];

function updateTicYlabelsHidden(ticLabel) {
  if (ticLabel) {
    if (ticYlabelsHidden.includes(ticLabel)) {
      ticYlabelsHidden.splice(ticYlabelsHidden.indexOf(ticLabel), 1);
      //ticYlabels.push(ticLabel);
    } else {
      ticYlabelsHidden.push(ticLabel);
    }
  }
  initializeTicYlabels();
}

function initializeTicYlabels() {
  ticYlabels = [];
  for (let n = 0; n < barTooltips.length; ++n) {
    let label = barTooltips[n].split(" ");
    label.shift();
    let ticLabel = label.join(' ');
    if (!ticYlabelsHidden.includes(ticLabel))
      ticYlabels.push(ticLabel);
  }
}

initializeTicYlabels();

let barBackgroundColor = [];
let maxColors = 20;
let barDataSets = [];
for (let n = 0; n < barTooltips.length; ++n) {
  barBackgroundColor.push(rcBackgroundColors[n % maxColors]);
  barDataSets[n] = {
    label: [ticYlabels[n]],
    data: [barData[n]],
    backgroundColor: rcBackgroundColors[n % maxColors],
    borderColor: rcBackgroundColors[n % maxColors],
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBorderWidth: 0
  };
}

let xMax = Math.max(...barData);
xMax += xMax / 10;
let pktSrcBarChartConfig = {
  animation: false,
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    datasets: barDataSets,
    labels: ticYlabels,
  },

  options: {
    barValueSpacing: 10,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'y',
      callbacks: {
        title: function() {
          return '';
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem) {
          return barTooltips[tooltipItem.index] + ':  ' + tooltipItem.xLabel + ' KB/sec';
        }
      }
    },
    legend: false,
    legendCallback: function(chart) {
      let text = [];
      text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');
      for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
        text.push('<li><i class="fa fa-1x fa-check-square" style="color: ' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + ';">');
        if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
          text.push('&nbsp;<span style="color: black; font-size: 16px; font-family: ubuntu monospace">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label);
        }
        text.push('</i></li>');
      }
      text.push('</ul>');
      return text.join('');
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Bandwidth',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
      fontSize: 18,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'KB/sec',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
          fontSize: 18,
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          suggestedMax: xMax,
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        //id: 'ip',
        //type: 'category',
        barPercentage: 0.8,
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        maxBarThickness: 30,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Packet Source',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
          fontSize: 18,
        },
      }]
    },
    
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return value;
        },
        display: function(context) {
          return context.chart.isDatasetVisible(context.datasetIndex);
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}

function legendClickCallback(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  let target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  while (target.nodeName !== 'LI') {
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  let parent = target.parentElement;
  let chartId = parseInt(parent.classList[0].split("-")[0], 10);
  let chart = Chart.instances[chartId];
  let index = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children).indexOf(target);

  if (chart.isDatasetVisible(index)) {
    target.classList.add('hiddenItem');
    target.firstChild.classList.remove('fa-check-square');
    target.firstChild.classList.add('fa-square');
    chart.data.datasets[index].hidden = true;
  } else {
    target.classList.remove('hiddenItem');
    target.firstChild.classList.remove('fa-square');
    target.firstChild.classList.add('fa-check-square');
    chart.data.datasets[index].hidden = false;
  }
  updateTicYlabelsHidden(target.innerText.trim());
  barChart.data.labels = ticYlabels;
  barChart.update();
}

barChart = new Chart(ctx, pktSrcBarChartConfig);
// Generate custom html legend with checkboxes instead of colored rectangles
let myLegendContainer = document.getElementById("legendDiv");
myLegendContainer.innerHTML = barChart.generateLegend();

// Bind onClick event to all LI-tags of the legend
let legendItems = myLegendContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (let i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i += 1) {
  legendItems[i].addEventListener("click", legendClickCallback, false);
}
```

```css
[class="0-legend"] {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: table-row;
}

[class="0-legend"] li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

[class="0-legend"] li.hiddenItem span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="legendDiv" class="noselect"></div>
<div id="container" style="width:95%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: The title for this question should read "chartjs horizontal bar chart spacing broken between 2.7.1 and 2.7.2"---I had a typo in the version, but can't figure out a way to edit it other than post this comment.